# Vitest-mock-extended deepMock imported with type 'any'

Tags: typescript, testing, vitest

I am learning test using vitest and vitest-mock-extended. I have created the mock of 'shorterServices' and it is exported with the inferred type of mockDeep()
However, when importing it, it is imported with the type 'any'.

I previously mocked the prismaClient and when I import it it does so with its corresponding type. What could be the error?

**mock**/shorter.services.ts:

```
import { beforeEach } from 'vitest'
import { mockDeep, mockReset } from 'vitest-mock-extended'
import type { shorterService } from '@/services/shorter.services'

beforeEach(() => {
  mockReset(shorterServiceMock)
})

const shorterServiceMock = mockDeep<typeof shorterService>()

export default shorterServiceMock
```

And this is the mock of the prismaClient, which does work correctly

```
import type { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import { beforeEach } from 'vitest'
import { mockDeep, mockReset } from 'vitest-mock-extended'

beforeEach(() => {
  mockReset(prisma)
})

const client = mockDeep<PrismaClient>()
const clientExtended = client.$extends({...
})
const prisma = mockDeep<typeof clientExtended>()

export default prisma
```

I have copied the shorterService mock code and put it in the same test file and it works, but when I move it to a different file it does not infer its type